# Не сохраняет html символы в произвольных полях Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет!

Есть такой вопрос. В админки WP вывел произвольные поля кастомно (на фронте тоже вывел). Все ок, сохраняет, инфу выводит, но не сохраняет html символы. Т.е. я не могу в тесте сделать абзац и все такое.

Как сделать, чтобы произвольное поле сохраняло html символы?

Код в functions.php

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_extra_fields', 1);

function my_extra_fields() {
    add_meta_box( 'extra_fields', 'Дополнительные поля', 'extra_fields_box_func', 'post', 'normal', 'high'  );
}

// код блока
function extra_fields_box_func( $post ){
?>
    <p>Заголовок укр<br><label><input type="text" name="extra[title_uk]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'title_uk', 1); ?>" style="width:100%" /> </label></p>

    <p>Текст укр:
        <textarea type="text" name="extra[content_uk]" style="width:100%;height:250px;"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'content_uk', 1); ?></textarea>
    </p>



    <input type="hidden" name="extra_fields_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(__FILE__); ?>" />
<?php
}


// включаем обновление полей при сохранении
add_action('save_post', 'my_extra_fields_update', 0);

/* Сохраняем данные, при сохранении поста */
function my_extra_fields_update( $post_id ){
    // базовая проверка
    if (
           empty( $_POST['extra'] )
        || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['extra_fields_nonce'], __FILE__ )
        || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id )
        || wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )
    )
        return false;

    // Все ОК! Теперь, нужно сохранить/удалить данные
    $_POST['extra'] = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['extra'] );
    foreach( $_POST['extra'] as $key => $value ){
        if( empty($value) ){
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key ); // удаляем поле если значение пустое
            continue;
        }

        update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value ); // add_post_meta() работает автоматически
    }

    return $post_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке

```
$_POST['extra'] = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['extra'] );
```

вы чистите строку от любых html-символов. Это нормально для заголовка, но неприемлемо для текста. Там надо применять `wp_kses_post()`.

Вот полностью рабочий код, приведённый к стандартам кодирования WordPress.

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_extra_fields', 1 );

function my_extra_fields() {
    add_meta_box( 'extra_fields', 'Дополнительные поля', 'extra_fields_box_func', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

// Код блока.
function extra_fields_box_func( $post ) {
    ?>
    <p>Заголовок укр<br><label><input type="text" name="extra[title_uk]"
                                      value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title_uk', 1 ); ?>"
                                      style="width:100%"/> </label></p>

    <p>Текст укр:
        <textarea type="text" name="extra[content_uk]"
                  style="width:100%;height:250px;"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'content_uk', 1 ); ?></textarea>
    </p>


    <input type="hidden" name="extra_fields_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( __FILE__ ); ?>"/>
    <?php
}


// Включаем обновление полей при сохранении.
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_extra_fields_update', 0 );

/**
 * Сохраняем данные при сохранении поста
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post id.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function my_extra_fields_update( $post_id ) {
    // Базовая проверка.
    $nonce = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'extra_fields_nonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $extra = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'extra', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY );
    if (
        empty( $extra )
        || ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, __FILE__ )
        || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id )
        || wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Все ОК! Теперь нужно сохранить/удалить данные.
    $extra['title_uk']   = isset( $extra['title_uk'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $extra['title_uk'] ) : '';
    $extra['content_uk'] = isset( $extra['content_uk'] ) ? wp_kses_post( $extra['content_uk'] ) : '';
    foreach ( $extra as $key => $value ) {
        if ( empty( $value ) ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key ); // удаляем поле если значение пустое.
            continue;
        }

        update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value ); // add_post_meta() работает автоматически.
    }

    return $post_id;
}
```

Comment: Супер!!! Спасибо!!! Ну да, как сразу не увидел array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['extra'] );
Оно же очищает! Спасибо огромное!!!! 2 дня пытался через wpautop()